# How to fit an ARIMA model with seasonality in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, seasonality

I have a set of monthly data and detected seasonality. The ACF and PACF is shown below. How can I set c=(p,d,q) for non-seasonal part and c=(P,D,Q) for seasonal part based on the figures.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read the help page `?arima`. Use

```
arima(x, order = c(p,d,q), seasonal = list(order = c(P, D, Q), period=12))
```

in your nomenclature.

Even better, try `auto.arima()` and allow R to find good orders.

Comment: what possible value of p d q and P D Q you would suggest based on the ACF and PACF? Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using `auto.arima()` and letting R worry about finding a good model.